# Find the total capacity of files in a directory in HDFS according to date

Tags: linux, unix, hdfs

I have some files in a directory in HDFS and I want to calculate the total capacity of the files with date MARCH 8:

I tried this but nothing happened:

```
 hdfs dfs -ls /path/ | grep "Mar  8" | awk '{print $9}' | xargs echo hdfs dfs -du -h | awk '{ print; total += $1 }; END { print "total size: ",total }' | tail -n 1
```

I want for example to print 6 GB

Comment: Does this work? `hdfs dfs -find /path/ -newermt 2021-03-06 ! -newermt 2021-03-07 -printf '%s\n' | awk '{sum+=$1}; END{print sum}'`

Comment: @Nobody It throws an Unexpected argument -newermt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
hdfs dfs -ls /path/ | grep "Mar  9" | awk '{print $9}' | xargs hdfs dfs du -k | awk '{ print; total += $1 }; END { print "total size: ",total }' | tail -n 1
```

This prints the total capacity of the folder.